# Calling a component method from another component when using react-redux ?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm making app with react native that will have an audio player, this audio player will has it's on view with its controllers (Play, Stop, Skip...) how ever i need this audio player to be able to be controlled from multiple components. Right now i'm using redux to manage the application state that includes the player state (isPlaying, currentTrack...).

So my question is, how's the best or a good way for another component to perform actions over the player ?

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern for controlling behavior is that of passing behaviors (functions) down via props to other components.

In your case of shared control of a media player, you might have something with this architecture (pseudocode):

```
togglePlayer(){
   this.setState(state=>({playing: !state.playing}))
   //or
   dispatch(togglePlayerActionCreator())
}

<Player isPlaying={this.state.playing} />

<ThingThatControlsPlayer onSomeEvent={this.togglePlayer} />

<ThingThatControlsPlayer onSomeEvent={this.togglePlayer} />
```

In this case, there is a common function that each sibling component can access, via a function passed as a prop. The player would then react to some state change as a result of that function being called. Whether this is internal component state or redux store passed into the component as props, the *pattern* is the same. Keep in mind that with the react+redux architecture *state flows down, and events flow up*